# How to link openssl statically in my C++ shared library on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, dll, openssl

I want to link openssl library statically in my C++ shared library project because I want to distribute my shared library in a single `dll` file.

So I added the following codes in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(std OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

And here are the logs of cmake:

```
"C:\Users\Jerry Chou\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8617.54\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Users/Jerry Chou/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8617.54/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S "C:\Users\Jerry Chou\CLionProjects\rexStdlib" -B "C:\Users\Jerry Chou\CLionProjects\rexStdlib\cmake-build-debug"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Jerry Chou/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8617.54/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Jerry Chou/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/223.8617.54/bin/mingw/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenSSL: C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/libcrypto.lib (found version "1.1.1s")  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Jerry Chou/CLionProjects/rexStdlib/cmake-build-debug
```

However, the shared library couldn't be loaded. I checked its behavior with ProcessMonitor. The library tried to load `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` but failed. How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure to have installed OpenSSL static libs? `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS` allows to find static libs before shared libs (on Windows it looks for import lib of dll) when there are installed together, but it doesn't prevent to find shared libs if static are not installed.

Comment: On Windows, both static and dynamic libs are ultimately presented to the consuming application as .lib files. (unlike Unix flavors where the object archives (.a) files and shared object libraries (.so), are distinguishable). If you have any doubts, (1) look in your openssl/bin folder. If there are DLLs *and* the .lib files in the lib folder seem 'small', then you likely have an OpenSSL shared-lib build, and those .lib files are import libraries. . It is possible to build *both* and mount them in the same target location with extra effort.

Comment: Did you build OpenSSL yourself?  That's the main thing to do.  There's options in the make file for building as a static lib instead of as a DLL+stublib.

Comment: Might help (although built with *VStudio*) [\[GitHub\]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/OpenSSL](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/OpenSSL).

Comment: Now I found a solution to this problem, I use cmake to find the openssl dll files on Windows platform and put them in my binary output directory and distribute my binaries with them. I don't know if this is correct or not.